# Change resolution by console

Tags: ubuntu, x11, screen-resolution

I changed my ubuntu screen-resolution and now it's everything black and I can't change it againd to the old resolution. What do I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This question belongs on SuperUser.com

In the mean time, there is a file in `/etc/X11` called `xorg.conf` which contains the screen configuration. There is probably also one or more backup files which contain previous configurations. You can try something like this:

```
cd /etc/X11
sudo cp xorg.conf xorg.conf.BAD
sudo cp name-of-backup-file xorg.conf
```

Then switch back to X using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or similar and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to reload X.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yes! I did it many times.